# How can you create Results after creating records?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a method that should return `Results`, either by successfully querying, or by creating the records if they don't exist.

Something like:

```
class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var token = ""

    static let realm = try! Realm()

    class func findOrCreate(token token: String) -> Results<MyObject> {
        // either it's found ...
        let tokenResults = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("token = '\(token)'")
        if !tokenResults.isEmpty {
            return tokenResults
        }
        // ... or it's created
        let newObject = MyObject()
        newObject.token = token
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newObject)
        }
        // However, the next line results in the following error:
        // 'Results<_>' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
        return Results(newObject)
    }
}
```

Maybe I should just be returning `[MyObject]` from this method.  Is there any benefit to trying to keep it as `Results` instead of `Array`?  I guess I'd lose any benefit of postponed evaluation since I'm already using `isEmpty` within the method, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Results` is an auto-updating *view* into underlying data in a Realm, which is why you can't construct it directly. So instead of `return Results(newObject)`, you should `return tokenResults`, which will contain your newly added object, again because `Results` is an auto-updating view.

Comment: Ah right, thanks!  I was thinking that maybe I should be able to create a `Results` as though it were a simple primary key query, just so that the successful case doesn't have to lose the ability to be returned as `Results`.  But yea of course, now it seems so obvious.  Thanks again!